# How to increase an account nonce on web3js?

Tags: web3js, truffle, javascript, truffle-migration, nonce

i'm running a script using web3js in which one i have my accounts[0] that is running 2 transactions.

When i do:
await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(accounts[0]) ,  i receive X (number) as a response.

Then submitting first transaction, till here all is ok!

I run again:
await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(accounts[0]), now i receive X+1 as a response. All good till here.

Now here is the problem, i submit the 2nd Tx with accounts[0]. And it failed with "nonce too low" as an error message. The same transaction is ok when running with another account, like accounts[2] or whatever.

I read a lot about that I need to increase nonce of accounts[0], cause it seems that web3js keep in memory the same nonce for the whole script (so same nonce for every transaction of the same account in ths script).  but i don't find how to do so with web3js.

```
//transaction 1: 

const receipt = await web3.eth .sendSignedTransaction("0x" + serializedTx.toString("hex")) .catch((err) => console.log(err));

const nonceUpdated = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(myAddress); console.log("nonceUpdated =>", nonceUpdated); 

//transaction 2: 

await myDeFiProject .foo(accounts[1], amountFooFunction, { from: accounts[0] }) .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

Here is the problem transaction 2 going to failed with "nonce too low" despite on my console.log i have an updated nonce. Looks like web3js keep the same nonce for all the transaction related to accounts[0] so there must be a way to increment it?

Thanks

Comment: You could get the nonce at the script start and then increase it when creating a transaction. That way you will only call getTransactionCount once at the beginning.

Comment: thanks Ismael, the thing is that i don't know how to increase it. Let me show you how it goes in my code:

` 
//transaction 1:

const receipt = await web3.eth
    .sendSignedTransaction("0x" + serializedTx.toString("hex"))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));

const nonceUpdated = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(myAddress);
  console.log("nonceUpdated =>", nonceUpdated);

//transaction 2:

  await myDeFiProject
    .foo(accounts[1], amountFooFunction, { from: accounts[0] })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
`

Comment: It will look better if you edit the question to add that snippet of code. In javascript numbers are usually wrapped around libraries like BN o BigNumber because they don't fit in javascript's native numbers. That libraries usually provide function to increase them like add or something similar.

Comment: updated Ismael, thanks, sorry i'm new here